# Rails TurboLinks Page Loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm using the following code to show some loading content:

```
$(document)
    .on 'page:fetch', ->
        $('#page-loading').show()
    .on 'page:load', ->
        $('#page-loading').hide()
```

The problem I am having is the browser back button.  If I click on the browser back button the loading bar is displayed on the previous page.

Is there a way to hide the div#page-loading when a user clicks the back button in the browser?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this could be useful:

```
 page:change 





$(document)
    .on 'page:fetch', ->
        $('#page-loading').show()
    .on 'page:load', ->
        $('#page-loading').hide()
    .on 'page:change', -> 
        $('#page-loading').hide()
```